# npm config set msvs_version does not work? (node-gyp)

Tags: c++, node.js, visual-studio, npm, node-gyp

npm config set msvs_version does not work and I still get `msvs_version not set from command line or npm config`.

I have all the necessary paths set and I have Visual Studio 2017, 2019 and 2022 installed with the necessary C++ thingys.

Full error:

```
gyp info using node-gyp@6.1.0
gyp info using node@16.17.0 | win32 | x64
gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.7 found at "C:\Python310\python.exe"
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
gyp ERR! find VS running in VS Command Prompt, installation path is:
gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community"
gyp ERR! find VS - will only use this version
gyp ERR! find VS unknown version "undefined" found at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools"
gyp ERR! find VS unknown version "undefined" found at "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community"
gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2019 (16.11.32901.82) found at:
gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community"
gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
gyp ERR! find VS - found VC++ toolset: v142
gyp ERR! find VS - found Windows SDK: 10.0.19041.0
gyp ERR! find VS - does not match this Visual Studio Command Prompt
gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2019 (16.11.32901.82) found at:
gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools"
gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
gyp ERR! find VS - found VC++ toolset: v142
gyp ERR! find VS - found Windows SDK: 10.0.18362.0
gyp ERR! find VS - does not match this Visual Studio Command Prompt
gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2017 (15.9.28307.2094) found at:
gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community"
gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
gyp ERR! find VS - found VC++ toolset: v141
gyp ERR! find VS - missing any Windows SDK
gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2017 (15.9.28307.2094) found at:
gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools"
gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
gyp ERR! find VS - found VC++ toolset: v141
gyp ERR! find VS - found Windows SDK: 10.0.17763.0
gyp ERR! find VS - does not match this Visual Studio Command Prompt
gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
gyp ERR! find VS - not found
gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2013
gyp ERR! find VS - not found
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Fixed

---

- I found the dependency that was causing this error
- uninstalled it using `npm uninstall <dependency-name>`
- I redownloaded it as a devDependency with the `npm install <dependency-name> -save-dev`.

This fixed my issue for now but I do not know if this is a long term solution, I'll probably update this answer when I get to the phase of packaging the app.

Comment: What exactly did you delete?

Comment: @CodAvo Sorry it's been a really long time but I think I meant the package that was causing the problem, sorry I don't remember correctly. I'd like to try to help you if this doesn't help.